# LINQ Abbreviation Tip

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I've a LINQ query like below:

```
foreach (var property in from property in properties where property.Name != "Type" select property)
{
}
```

how would you go about making this statement more concise without using the actual extension method which looks unattractive (i.e. without using *.Where* like: `foreach (var property in properties.Where(...)`).

Comment: My spontaneous thought was "use the extension method instead; that will be much more to the point", but then I noticed you didn't want that. I find the query-style to be a bit too verbose for my own liking.

Comment: Apart from using a shorter identifier instead of `property` there isn't much you can do here. But personally I'd use `.Where(...)` because I prefer that syntax.

Comment: Yes it really is but then I have a mammoth query which looks really neat without extension methods with proper formatting so I'm curious.

Comment: Extensions methods look unattractive? I suppose that's up to the beholder... I think extension methods are much more readable than the SQL-like syntax. "var property in from property in properties" does not look silly to you?

Comment: Well yes, a bit of my personal taste I guess..

Comment: Do you find extension methods themselves unattractive or is it the lambda within? Like in `where(p => p.Name != "Type")

Comment: I'm trying not to use extensions to make the query look more 'English language' like but I guess that will have to change looking by the answers with 5+ lines of code..

Comment: Fewer lines of code doesn't always mean "more readable". Fluent syntax or not, I would still break your query in few lines, it's just more obvious this way

Answer (score 3):

You cant really..

You could put the query into a separate line.

```
var selectedProperties = from property in properties 
                         where property.Name != "Type" 
                         select property;

foreach (var property in selectedProperties)
{
}
```

Or you could factor the query out into a separate method if it is really huge.

```
foreach ( var property in ComplexSelectionOfProperties () )
...
```

But really I would say the exention method in this case is much neater. Its only when the queries get more complex and involve joins that the query syntax becomes tidier. (IMHO)

Answer (score 2):

Beauty is always in the eye of the beholder :)

However in such a case I would go create a method that filters non-Type properties and iterate over its results.

Something like this:

```
IEnumerable<IProperty> GetNonTypeProperties(IEnumerable<IProperty> properties)
{
    return (from property in properties where property.Name != "Type" select property);
}

void foo()
{
    foreach (var property in GetNonTypeProperties(properties))
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The lack of conciseness comes precisely from the sql style syntax : using a "dot" notation you will sensibly shorten your expression :

```
foreach (var property in properties.Where(property => property.Name != "Type"))
{
}
```

If you want to shorten the longest part which is obviously the boolean test, you have to put it elsewhere.

Either in the foreach loop itself :

```
foreach (var property in properties)
{
    if(property.Name != "Type")
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Either if a separate function :

```
foreach (var property in properties.Where(IsNotType))
{
}

//and farther :

bool IsNotType(Property p)
{
    return property.Name != "Type";
}
```

But anyway you want to perform a loop with a test on each element, so in a way or another you will have to code that and it will take a minimum amount of characters.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case that you don't like the lambda expression, not the extension method itself, you can make your own extension method with query inside, like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<Property> PropertiesExceptType(this IEnumerable<Property> properties) {
    return from property in properties 
           where property.Name != "Type" 
           select property;
}
```

and use it:

```
foreach(var property in properties.PropertiesExceptType()) {
    // ...
}
```

The good thing about encapsulating your query in separate method is that you can debug the method with loop and change the code on the fly (VS won't let you do this if you have a linq query right inside this method).

Comment: Oh and it's also the way to go if you need to apply this filter multiple times in your code, of course

Answer (score 1):

I honestly don't see anything wrong with `var propery in properties.Where()`, it's much better than any query expression in this context IMO. But if you want to stick with your query, at least introduce a variable:

```
var filteredProperties = from property in properties 
                         where property.Name != "Type" 
                         select property;
foreach(var property in filteredProperties)
{
   // ...
}
```

People who will read and debug it later will thank you. But I still think that extension method is the way to go here